# Upper bounds to covering a set with subsets of smaller size.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a set of size $n$ how many subsets of size $k$ of $n$ of that set do we need so that for every subset of size $m$ of $n$, that subset is also a subset of one of the subsets of size $k$? call this number $G(n,k,m)$

If it is not easy to compute could you provide a good lower bound? also I am particularly interested in the case where $m=2$.

Even more specifically I would like to prove $G(16,5,2)\leq 16$

Comment: I hope you mean: $G(n,k,m)$ is the minimum size of family of $k$-subsets with the required property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A lower bound**: Let $G(n,k,2)$ be the minimum size of the set system consisting $k$-subsets of $[n]:=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ such that every $2$-subset of $[n]$ belongs to some member of the set system. An element of $[n]$ belongs to at least $\lceil \frac{n-1}{k-1} \rceil$ elements of the set system. This counts $n\lceil \frac{n-1}{k-1} \rceil$ with repetition. But, every element of the set system is counted exactly $k$ times. Hence, the lower bound, $$\frac{n\lceil \frac{n-1}{k-1} \rceil}{k}\le G(n,m,2)$$

Comment: $G(6,5,2)=3$ while you say $G(6,5,2)\leq 2.4$

Comment: What I have given is a lower bound -- as as asked in your question. Are you looking for an upper bound?

Comment: Oh, yes so sorry.